# Meteor collection schema: how to turn off data cleaning?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I use the `aldeed:collection2` package, and I attached a schema to my Meteor collection. It automatically performs data validation upon every insert/update. However, before inserting anything into the collection, it simply removes data fields that weren't declared in the schema.

I know I can turn this off by specifying `filter: false`:

```
MyCollection.insert(newDocument, { filter: false });
```

But I want it to be turned off by default, so I won't accidentally screw up my database by forgetting to update my schema.

How to turn off data filtering by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.clean` method gets always called, as stated in the [SimpleSchema docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema), therefore I don't think it's possible to disable that by default as you are asking:

> NOTE: The Collection2 package always calls clean before every insert, update, or upsert.